# Hide taxonomy when term is empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have this code, below and I want to change it to hide taxonomy when term is empty:

```
                <ul class="info-list">
                    <li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Actor:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <span><?php echo amy_movie_get_movie_taxomony( $post->ID, 'amy_actor' ); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Director:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <span><?php echo amy_movie_get_movie_taxomony( $post->ID, 'amy_director' ); ?></span>
                    </li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Genre:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <span><?php echo amy_movie_get_movie_taxomony( $post->ID, 'amy_genre' ); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Release:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <span><?php echo esc_attr( date( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $mdetails['movie_release'] ) ) ); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Language:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <span><?php echo esc_attr( $mdetails['movie_language'] ); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <?php if ( amy_get_option( 'enable_m_cinema', true ) == true ) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <label><?php echo esc_html__( 'Cinema:', 'amy-movie' ); ?></label>
                        <?php
                        if ( ! empty( $cinemas ) ) {
                            $numItems   = count( $cinemas );
                            $i          = 0;

                            foreach ( $cinemas as $cinema ) {
                                if ( ++$i === $numItems ) {
                                    $space = '';
                                } else {
                                    $space = ', ';
                                }

                                ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $cinema ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $cinema ); ?></a>
                                <?php echo esc_attr( $space ); ?>
                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
```

Comment: add an `if` wrapping the echo of the taxonomy

Answer (score 1):

Lots of Automattic themes do exactly this for standard tags and categories The Underscores starter theme, too. Straight from its source code up on GitHub:

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', '_s' ) );
if ( $categories_list ) {
    /* translators: 1: list of categories. */
    printf( '' . esc_html__( 'Posted in %1$s', '_s' ) . '', $categories_list ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
}
```

Adapt as needed for your taxonomy.